# Sorting in Elasticsearch ignoring the date part of field

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a mapping of date field as :

```
 "created": {
          "type"  : "date",
          "format": "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
     },
```

Now when i sort based on the above field:

```
"sort":[
    {"created":{"order":"asc"}}
],
```

It takes only time part of the date while sorting and ignores the date part.

```
{
    "_index": "somehting",
    "_type": "UserActivity",
    "_id": "81574",
    "_score": null,
    "_source": {
      "created": "2016-03-29 00:00:07",
      "appCode": "appcode",
      "userId": "100008057363993"
    },
    "sort": [
      "00:00:07"
    ]
  },
```

How do  sort based on the whole date?
Please note i cannot use scripting as its disabled on production server and i cannot re-index..

Adding the total mapping:

```
{
  "someIndex": {
    "mappings": {
      "UserActivity": {
        "_timestamp": {
          "enabled": true,
          "store": true,
          "format": "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
        },
        "properties": {
          "_table": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "_tableat": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "activity": {
            "properties": {
              "_table": {
                "type": "string"
              },
              "_tableat": {
                "type": "string"
              },
              "clientId": {
                "type": "integer"
              },
              "code": {
                "type": "string"
              },
              "created": {
                "type": "date",
                "format": "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
              },
              "foreignName": {
                "type": "string"
              },
              "frequency": {
                "type": "integer"
              },
              "id": {
                "type": "long"
              },
              "lastUpdated": {
                "type": "date",
                "format": "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
              },
              "name": {
                "type": "string"
              },
              "points": {
                "type": "long"
              },
              "strategy": {
                "type": "string"
              }
            }
          },
          "activityId": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "appCode": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "clientId": {
            "type": "long"
          },
          "created": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "details": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "foreignName": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "id": {
            "type": "long"
          },
          "lastUpdated": {
            "type": "date",
            "format": "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
          },
          "notes": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "userId": {
            "type": "long"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you 100% certain that the `created` field is really a date? Please run the following command and update your question with the result you get: `curl -XGET localhost:9200/somehting/_mapping/UserActivity`

Comment: Val, at the every beginning of the post i have pasted the mapping only.

Comment: You've pasted the mapping you **think** you have, but is it really the one you have? That's why I'd like to see the result fo this: `curl -XGET localhost:9200/somehting/_mapping/UserActivity`

Comment: hi Val, have updated the post to include the total mapping.

Comment: There you go, do you see that the `created` field is a `string`? You have another `activity.created` field which is a date, though. Sounds like you have some mapping mess here. However, if you sort by `lastUpdated` it will work as this is a real date field.

Comment: oh i got what u r saying. I will try and let you know. Thanks Val